# Leaflet heatmap renders black gradient - no colors

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using leaflet (http://leafletjs.com/) and the leaflet-heat.js heatmap plugin for it (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat).

I've added them to my project, loaded the map, the data and finally added a heatmap layer on top, but end up with this distribution of black dots:
[image: heatmap distribution and color without config]

```
var map = new L.map('map', {zoomControl: false, tap: false}).setView(careLatLng, 7);

var baseLayer = 
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

var heat = L.heatLayer(testData).addTo(map);
```

Essentially straight out of this demo: http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/demo/

I don't understand why my heatmap is rendered in black and not in a gradient though. I thought I may have missed something in the config and tried adding this to ensure I have colors defined:

```
       var heat = L.heatLayer(testData,{            
        minOpacity: 0.5,
        radius: 20,
        blur: 50, 
        maxZoom: 7,
        max: 4,
        gradient: {0: "#000000",0.2: "#570000",0.4: "#ff0000",0.6: "#ffc800",0.8: "#ffff00",1: "#FFFFFF"}            
    }).addTo(map);
```

Which ends up rendering this:

[image: heatmap distribution and color with config]

Which leads me to believe that the config is working and I'm just missing something in terms of gradient. But as you can see in the config, I've set gradient colors but the browser still renders them as black!?

I checked this entry: [Leaflet Heatmap did not produce gradient color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060670/leaflet-heatmap-did-not-produce-gradient-color) and their values are the ones I used for my config, I'm stumped.

Comment: What is the max value of your heat data? In the copied options you have `max: 4`, which is probably not right for your data.

Comment: every data point gets a fix 0.2 - I've added the gradient steps in same fashion. Played around with the max value too and it doesn't change the color from black to anything else. Just stays black/grey gradient

Comment: Try removing blur, max & maxZoom. `blur` is probably the problem. I've managed to use your gradient. Though I still don't see why you should get black/grey. see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nettaB/5v777wg3/8/). Question: which leaflet version are you using?

Comment: using leaflet v1.3.1 removing blur, max & maxZoom changes appearance but not the color if the heatmap gradient. I have no idea what's going on with the colors

Comment: I might be able to help if you'll create a fiddle. Can't investigate further without it,.

Comment: Here's a fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/vn7md6j6/11 and as you can see it works perfectly fine in the fiddle, just not in my app. mmmh, weird

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was caused by the framework that this component was running on. I used it inside a Lightning Component and after changing the versions (v42 to v38) of the framework it ran on, I managed to get the intended colors:

[image]

Thanks @NettaB for your help!